# Ubuntu freezes on boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, startup

I've had this problem more than 2 years. I tried to install Ubuntu on ASUS N552 laptop alongside Windows.

On some releases it hangs on live boot, and on the some others it hangs after installation.

I have tried Ubuntu 14.04, 15.04, 15.10, 16.04, 16.10, 17.04, 17.10!
among them I could install Ubuntu 15.10 but it is old unsupported release now.

Furthermore, it cannot recognize double touch and have some other issues.
On some releases live USB boot has not any problem but after installation it crashes on startup. on some the others it crashes on live USB startup too.

After that I tried Linux mint 18 but sometimes it hangs on live USB startup and finally it hangs all times after installation.

I've googled this problem for two years and every time I get tired of trying different solutions which has not any effects on my issue.

Please note that I'm trying to boot Ubuntu alongside windows 10 (dual boot)
and I have disabled secure boot.

Additional Information:

- Loptop: Asus N552
- Ram: 16GB
- Hard drive: 2 TB (128 GB SSD which windows is installed in)
- Graphics Adapter: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M (4GB)
- Processor: Intel Core i7 HQ

Comment: Have you done the instructions here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: Also, try to create your live USB using [multiusb](http://multibootusb.org/page_download/) and use a USB 2.0 stick, DO NOT use USB 3.0 sticks.

Comment: i tried but it has not any effect

Comment: I was using the same model with Linux mint 18.1 without issues, and installed ubuntu mate 18.4 . On USB and after install, I had already experienced a freeze 3 times in the last 2 hours. I just switched to the NVIDIA driver, and for now, no freeze.